# How do I use grep and tr with pipe as a bash command in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, groovy, grep

im using a grep command with tr to access a version from a file which in my current directory.
The grep command works but not in the context of the Jenkinsfile as a variable.

I have this:

```
            grepVersion='${grep -we "^version:" myconfig.yaml | tr -d "version:[:blank:]"}'
```

I want this:

```
myPath='something_"${grepVersion}"'
```

as this:

```
    echo "{$myPath}"
output: something_0.0.2
```

If tried a lot, would be great if someone could help me with this.

my Jenkinsfile looks something like this:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    
                    echo "build something"
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        stage('Deploy'){
            steps{
                script {
                    
                    #grep version from file 

                    grepVersion='${grep -we "^version:" myconfig.yaml | tr -d "version:[:blank:]"}'                 
        
                    #access archivePath 
                    archivePath="${WORKSPACE}/archives/${env.JOB_NAME}_"${grepVersion}".mtar"
                    
                    #deploy something with arhivePath
                    sh 'XX deploy "${archivePath}" -f'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This command works and accesses the correct version:

```
grep -we "^version:" myconfig.yaml |tr -d "version:[:blank:]"
```

I have the following file in my path where I want to access **version: 0.0.2** as **0.0.2** to concatenate this to my archivePath variable.

```
ID
Name
version: 0.0.2



different_version: 0.0.2
    
    
different_version: 0.0.3
```

The following command works on bash shell and can acces the correct version: **0.0.2**

```
grep -we "^version:" myconfig.yaml |tr -d "version:[:blank:]"
```

But it won't work with the Jenkins fileand and groovy context.
If have tried the following commands to access **0.0.2** to use it as a bash variable :

**Here the "^" makes a problem:**

```
grepVersion=${grep -we "^version:" myconfig.yaml |tr -d "version:[:blank:]"}
```

**Here the commands wont resolve because of the double quotes:**

```
grepVersion="${grep -we '^version:' myconfig.yaml |tr -d 'version:[:blank:]'"'
```

...

```
grepVersion='$(grep -we '^version:' myconfig.yaml |tr -d 'version:[:blank:]')"
```

and so on haven' found a solution yet.

Thanks for your help already.

Comment: `tr -d 'version'` will remeve every `e`, `i`, `n`, `o`, `r`, `s`, and `v` character. That's almost certainly not what you want. Are you looking for `sed -n 's/^version:[[:blank:]]*//p' myconfig.yaml`?

Comment: You also need to wrap the whole grep command in a sh call.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, you both were right!

The following command works for me:

```
grepVersion=sh 'sed -n s/^version:[[:blank:]]*//p mta.yaml'
```